# How to redirect (or bring back) /services/ pages after migrating from Wordpress to Shopify?

Tags: wordpress, redirect, migration, shopify, http-status-code-301

My problem is that my client has migrated from Wordpress to Shopify, and there were some important pages on the site under the /services/ folder. I wanted to redirect them to their new pages after the migration, which are /pages/ pages.

Shopify has reserved /services/ URLs, however. Therefore I cannot redirect mydomain.com/services/some-services-page to mydomain.com/pages/some-services-page.

Additionally, I cannot change the URLs of the /pages/ pages to /services/ pages.

What would be the next best step here? It seems like a significant limitation of Shopify, as any pages you want to migrate from another CMS that have /services/, apparently can't be redirected, and you lose the SEO value. Those pages are now returning 404 and there doesn't seem to be anything I can do about it, or am I missing something?

I've had some back and forth with Shopify support, which ultimately ends with them saying its a limitation of Shopify and I should submit a feature request. I appreciate any advice you might have.

Comment: You'll have to explain the situation to your client, Jake. There's no way around that. They'll have to live with this if they plan on continue using Shopify.

Comment: Thanks @cabrerahector, I will for sure let them know. The upside is that these pages didn't have any backlinks and held very few keyword positions.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually create redirects from old relative urls to new ones on shopify by going to `[yourstore].myshopify.com/admin/redirects`

If you want to track which pages customers are exactly hitting and getting 404's, you can use app Transportr:
https://apps.shopify.com/transportr

It tracks which pages are getting 404, and you can also create redirects directly from an app

Comment: I tried that, but I cannot redirect mydomain.com/services/some-services-page to mydomain.com/pages/some-services-page. Shopify's docs state: You can't redirect URLs that begin with the following prefixes: /apps, /application, /cart, /carts, /orders, /shop, or /services.

Comment: You're right, it doesn't seem to be workaround for that

Comment: Yeah, that's a huge Shopify SEO issue in my opinion - if you migrate from a WP site and have any of those as top-level folders, you just can't redirect them. Or at least thats how it seems...